# Getting an array of specific key/value pairs from JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

Beginner here - I'd like to create an array for my cities of the world type ahead project from a JSON file. I've fetched the data, now I would like to extract 2 key/value pairs (called name/country) and push them into a new string array that will have the syntax:

```
const arr = ["name, country", "name, country", "name, country"...]
```

Here is a sample of the data:

```
[]:
0: {country: "Andorra", geonameid: 3040051, name: "les Escaldes", subcountry: "Escaldes-Engordany"}
1: {country: "Andorra", geonameid: 3041563, name: "Andorra la Vella", subcountry: "Andorra la Vella"}
2: {country: "United Arab Emirates", geonameid: 290594, name: "Umm al Qaywayn", subcountry: "Umm al Qaywayn"}
3: {country: "United Arab Emirates", geonameid: 291074, name: "Ras al-Khaimah", subcountry: "Raʼs al Khaymah"}...
```

I know I have to use `.push()` and `.forEach()` or a for loop but I'm not sure how to go about it. Can anyone show me how?

Comment: `data.forEach(i => arr.push(i.name + ", " + i.country))` should do it

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, noticed just know, thankx

Comment: ``data.map(i => arr.push(`${i.name} , ${i.country}`)``

Comment: [Demo for my comment](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/IckyPrevailingMenus#index.js)

Comment: @AbishekKumar you are still using `map` like `forEach`. That should be a `forEach` not `map`.

Comment: Yeah, you might as well use `forEach` if you're gonna do it like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const data = [{country: "Andorra", geonameid: 3040051, name: "les Escaldes", subcountry: "Escaldes-Engordany"},
{country: "Andorra", geonameid: 3041563, name: "Andorra la Vella", subcountry: "Andorra la Vella"},
{country: "United Arab Emirates", geonameid: 290594, name: "Umm al Qaywayn", subcountry: "Umm al Qaywayn"},
{country: "United Arab Emirates", geonameid: 291074, name: "Ras al-Khaimah", subcountry: "Raʼs al Khaymah"}]

const arr = data.map(i => `${i.name} , ${i.country}`);
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like so:

```
const arr = data.map(city => city.name + ", " + city.country);
```

`arr` will be a new array of the same length as `data` where each `city` object in `data` is mapped to the string `city.name + ", " + city.country`.

**Demo:**

```js
const data = [ {country: "Andorra", geonameid: 3040051, name: "les Escaldes", subcountry: "Escaldes-Engordany"}, {country: "Andorra", geonameid: 3041563, name: "Andorra la Vella", subcountry: "Andorra la Vella"}, {country: "United Arab Emirates", geonameid: 290594, name: "Umm al Qaywayn", subcountry: "Umm al Qaywayn"}, {country: "United Arab Emirates", geonameid: 291074, name: "Ras al-Khaimah", subcountry: "Raʼs al Khaymah"} ];

const arr = data.map(city => city.name + ", " + city.country);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple Solution with forEach

```js
countries = [
  {country: "Andorra", geonameid: 3040051, name: "les Escaldes", subcountry: "Escaldes-Engordany"},
  {country: "Andorra", geonameid: 3041563, name: "Andorra la Vella", subcountry: "Andorra la Vella"},
  {country: "United Arab Emirates", geonameid: 290594, name: "Umm al Qaywayn", subcountry: "Umm al Qaywayn"},
  {country: "United Arab Emirates", geonameid: 291074, name: "Ras al-Khaimah", subcountry: "Raʼs al Khaymah"}
]

let arr = [];

let result = [];

countries.forEach((country, index) => {
    let nameStr = `${country.name}, ${country.country}`
    result.push(nameStr);
})

console.log(result)

//output
//["les Escaldes Andorra", "Andorra la Vella Andorra", "Umm al Qaywayn United Arab Emirates", "Ras al-Khaimah United Arab Emirates"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce function if you want to:

```
arr.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, (`${curr.name}, ${curr.country}`)], []);
```

It will return your values in your desired format.

Example below.

```js
const arr = [
    {country: 'Andorra', geonameid: 3040051, name: 'les 1', subcountry: 'Escaldes-Engordany'},
    {country: 'Turkey', geonameid: 3040021, name: 'les Escaldes', subcountry: 'aaaa'},
    {country: 'IDK', geonameid: 3040021, name: 'Wow', subcountry: 'aaaa'}
];
const custom = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, (`${curr.name}, ${curr.country}`)], []);
console.log(custom);
```